# ffmpeg: slow video by dropping frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to take a 60fps video and drop every other frame, making it 30fps without changing the duration. I have not been able to find this online; everything seems to be about changing the frame rate and the duration simultaneously, i.e. to make it appear in slow-motion.

Answer (score 1):

`-r 30` should do the trick.

Changing playback speed requires using [additional filters](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video).

Comment: So, `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 30 output.mp4`?

Comment: Yes, that's the most basic variant of this command.